# Objective C static const in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

How write this Objective C code in Swift?

```
#import "FFTViewController.h"

//only this part
static vDSP_Length const FFTViewControllerFFTWindowSize = 4096;

@implementation FFTViewController
```

My idea is

```
let vDSP: vDSP_Length = 4096
```

i'm sure that is not correct, but i have no idea.

thanks for help

Update:

I want port this Objective C code to swift

```
#import "FFTViewController.h"

static vDSP_Length const FFTViewControllerFFTWindowSize = 4096;

@implementation FFTViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

//
// Setup the AVAudioSession. EZMicrophone will not work properly on iOS
// if you don't do this!
//
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error;
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error setting up audio session category: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
[session setActive:YES error:&error];
if (error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error setting up audio session active: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}

//
// Setup time domain audio plot
//
self.audioPlotTime.plotType = EZPlotTypeBuffer;
self.maxFrequencyLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

//
// Setup frequency domain audio plot
//
self.audioPlotFreq.shouldFill = YES;
self.audioPlotFreq.plotType = EZPlotTypeBuffer;
self.audioPlotFreq.shouldCenterYAxis = NO;

//
// Create an instance of the microphone and tell it to use this view controller instance as the delegate
//
self.microphone = [EZMicrophone microphoneWithDelegate:self];

//
// Create an instance of the EZAudioFFTRolling to keep a history of the incoming audio data and calculate the FFT.
//
self.fft = [EZAudioFFTRolling fftWithWindowSize:FFTViewControllerFFTWindowSize
                                     sampleRate:self.microphone.audioStreamBasicDescription.mSampleRate
                                       delegate:self];

//
// Start the mic
//
[self.microphone startFetchingAudio];
}
```

This is my beginning

```
import UIKit
import Accelerate


class ViewController: UIViewController, EZMicrophoneDelegate{

var mic: EZMicrophone!
var fft: EZAudioFFTRolling!
private let FFTViewControllerFFTWindowSize: vDSP_Length = 4096

override func loadView() {
    super.loadView()

    mic = EZMicrophone(delegate: self, startsImmediately: true)
    fft = EZAudioFFTRolling(windowSize: FFTViewControllerFFTWindowSize, sampleRate: mic.audioStreamBasicDescription().mSampleRate, delegate: self)


}


}
```

I becoming the following error:

compile fails with the following error:
"Cannot invoke initializer for type 'EZAudioFFTRolling' with an argument list of type '(windowSize: vDSP_Length, sampleRate: Float64, delegate: ViewController)'"

How is my problem? 
Sorry for this question i have no ObjectiveC background, is little challenge this port for me.

Thanks for Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're getting an error is in types. When you start typing EZAudioFFTRolling initializer in XCode, autocompletion helps you by displaying specification. It looks like this:

```
EZAudioFFTRolling(windowSize: vDSP_Length, sampleRate: Float, delegate: EZAudioFFTDelegate!)
```

If you compare parameters types from specification with actual values you're passing, you will figure out that mic.audioStreamBasicDescription().mSampleRate has Float64 type but should be Float (they're actually not the same) and self is not conforming to EZAudioFFTDelegate protocol. So after changing your line to this

```
fft = EZAudioFFTRolling(windowSize: FFTViewControllerFFTWindowSize, sampleRate: Float(mic.audioStreamBasicDescription().mSampleRate), delegate: self)
```

and adding protocol conformance you will be able to build your code.

Swift is type safety in contradistinction to Objective-C, so it's common issues that all Objective-C developers have when start working with Swift. But errors are actually helping you, so read them attentively.

Comment: Ah ok, very interesting with float, thanks for your help